# What am I doing wrong with handling that global with the mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a global [global $host,$user,$passwd,$dbname;] for connecting to database in my script and then I use `mysqli_query` to perform a simple update query. There is a connection, but I keep getting this error:

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters,

What am I doing wrong with handling that global with the mysqli_query? Or is this error given when there is a problem with the query itself?

Comment: could you please post your code? thnx

Comment: the query looks something like this:
mysqli_query("UPDATE test.asdf
SET
username = '$username',
WHERE userid = '$userid',");

Comment: why you have a comma before the where clause? that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

It means that mysqli expects this:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($dbh, "SELECT ...");
```

and you're probably doing this:

```
 $result = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
```

The `mysqli` library is not a direct drop-in replacement for the older `mysql` one (note the lack of an `i`).

---

ok. simple short pseudo-code sample:

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect(....) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

function do_something($blah) {
   global $dbh;
   $result = mysqli_query($dbh, "SELECT ... $blah") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
}
```

Comment: I see... can I assign a variable to that global that connects to the db? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, $dbh is just the handle returned by `mysql_connect()`. You can do that in the global scope and use `mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbh']` or use the `global` keyword. Whatever works best for you. Most people here who've drank the OOP koolaid would suggest using a singleton, but for such things a global is perfectly acceptable in your own code.

Comment: Opp, I got a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL" when I assigned a variable to the global that connects the db...

Comment: `global $dbh = mysql_connect(...)` is not valid php syntax. `global $dbh; $dbh = mysql_connect(...)` would work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... this is how I have it now and it is shooting me errors: "$dbh = global $host,$user,$passwd,$dbname;" it doesn't shoot errors when it is solely "global $host,$user,$passwd,$dbname;" ... can you give me something to try with that in mind? I'm new to mysqli, I've always used the old one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should read the man page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Okay, I just read through it and better understand the nature of variables in the mysqli environment.. but I still don't know how to assign that variable to the globals properly for this database. Am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Unless you're in a function or in a class, every variable you create is in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Documentation: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

mysqli_query requires two parameters:

1. The database link
2. The query itself

Example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");
```

Comment: can I assign a variable to that global that connects to the db?

Comment: Yup!  You could definitely do that.  That's up to you.